# Foreach Loop SISS not moving to next ieration in case it fails

Tags: ssis

I am working with SSIS and inside a Foreach Loop I have got an "Analysis Services Execute DDL task". It has two iterations. If it fails on the first, the loop is not moving on to the second iteration. Is there any way I can make it move to next iteration?

Comment: You likely need to change the maximum error count of the task that is failing and the loop itself, if you haven't already.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: Probably, but I don't see why it's necessary.  Clearly the error itself doesn't bother you, so I fail to see why changing the maximum error count would.  You could always fix the error itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could [continue](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2014/05/continue-loop-after-error.html) a loop after an error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Likely what's happening is that the task's failure causes the loop container's `MaximumErrorCount` threshold to be met. This causes the loop's `ExecutionResult` to be set to failure, stopping further loop iterations. ([More on how `MaximumErrorCount` works](http://www.bengribaudo.com/blog/2014/08/22/3291/understanding-maximumerrorcount) [on my blog].)

If you don't want the task's error to stop further loop iterations, options include:

- Raise the loop's `MaximumErrorCount` to a higher value or set it to infinity.
- Set the loop's `ForceExecutionResult` to success to override `MaximumErrorCount`'s setting `ExecutionResult` to failure--keeps the loop iterating regardless of what `ExecutionResult` gets set to.

  - For added flexibility, I think you can use an expression to control `ForceExecutionResult`.
- Add an `OnError` event handler on the task that stops event propagation--keeps the error from bubbling up from task to loop container.
- Get rid of the loop and create multiple Analysis Services Execute DDL Tasks--bypasses the problem altogether.

Without understanding the big picture of what you're trying to do, it's hard to make a recommendation as to which approach is best.